# Update ng-options value depending on another one

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I encountred a problem using Angular.Js ng-options directive, Here I have two select input:

```
    <select ng-model="vm.societie" ng-options="societie as societie.name for societie in vm.societies track by societie.id" ng-change="vm.getPrograms(vm.societie.id)">
    </select>
    <select name="filter-categories" ng-options="program.name for program in vm.programs" ng-model="vm.program">
    </select>
```

The getPrograms() function performs an HTTP request that fetch new data to update the values of vm.programs used to display options of the second select input.

```
function getPrograms (id) {
        serviceMain.programsGET(function(res, status, headers, config) {
            if (res.status > 400 && res.status < 600)
                alertMsg.send(res.status, "danger");
            else {
                if (id) {
                    vm.programs = [];
                    for (var i = 0;i < res.data.length;i++) {
                        if (res.data[i].society_id == id)
                            vm.programs.push(res.data[i]);
                    }
                    console.log(vm.programs);
                } else {
                    vm.programs = res.data;
                }
            }
        }, function(err, status, headers, config) {
            if (err)
                alertMsg.send(err.error.message, "danger");
        }, '?no_limit');
    }
```

Here I empty vm.programs then push the wanted data to display in the second select input.

My problem is that the data are updated but the binding doesn't show off on the display since the options are still visible on the second select.

**Edit 1:**
Here is a 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8nv3ctbb/2/)
 example of What I'm trying to reproduce at the exception that the getPrograms function is suposed to fetch data from an API.
I discovered that It does work as expected out of an HTTP request context.

**Edit 2:**
I manage to display new data by using ng-if directive as shown here:

```
vm.display = true;
function getPrograms (id) {
        vm.display = false;
        serviceMain.programsGET(function(res, status, headers, config) {
            if (res.status > 400 && res.status < 600)
                alertMsg.send(res.status, "danger");
            else {
                if (id) {
                    vm.programs = [];
                    for (var i = 0;i < res.data.length;i++) {
                        if (res.data[i].society_id == id)
                            vm.programs.push(res.data[i]);
                    }
                    console.log(vm.programs);
                    vm.display = true;
                } else {
                    vm.programs = res.data;
                    vm.display = true;
                }
            }
        }, function(err, status, headers, config) {
            if (err)
                alertMsg.send(err.error.message, "danger");
        }, '?no_limit');
    }
```

Http request does take times to resolve so DOM element need to be re-sync

Hope that was clear enough,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give any jsfiddle link to show your situation? Then it will be easy to provide you an appropriate solution rather then just guessing. Thanks.

Comment: @Sk.Tajbir Done in EDIT part, I didn't reproduce the HTTP request because it seems to be the reason of why data does not update.

Answer (score 0):

The API call in `getPrograms` is executed asynchronously. Hence, till the request completes, either the old data is shown or no data is shown. You need to make sure the user cannot select any option from the 2nd drop-down by disabling the drop-down or overlaying a loading indicator (something like [this](http://labs.voronianski.com/ngActivityIndicator.js/)) till the API returns data.

Comment: You are right I proceeded by hiding the select input just before the HTTP request then show it again and the data were updated.